# SharePoint Administrator as a career?

Tags: sharepoint-server, administration

Am working in a IT firm in India.
Recently I was offered to work as a SharePoint Admin, until now I was learning about SharePoint.
I wanted to ask does SharePoint Administrator have a good career ahead ? or is sticking to development better.
Also do the pay scales vary ?

Answer (score 2):

I don't think anybody give you concrete answer of this question. SharePoint itself very vast field. from power user to SharePoint administrator to developer to business analyst to architect. Every field having its own requirement and all are hot in the US market.

Pay range is very much depend upon the experince and company. selecting from developer to adminsitrator, If you already know development then i would say also learn the admin task it will put more weigh on your resume.

Check this blog, he explain and put the light on each area of sharepoint.

http://www.matthewjbailey.com/a-career-in-sharepoint/

another angle:
http://blogs.perficient.com/microsoft/2013/01/sharepoint-careers-three-best-routes-to-success/

Answer (score 2):

I agree wish Wasqas about it being a hard question to answer, but to give you some sense of the market today I would say that "Yes, there's a career as a SharePoint professional for some time ahead". However, I wouldn't myself want to restrict it to being only administrative tasks.

The demand for experienced SharePoint professionals still exist, but is vaguer now than it was just a few years ago - with that said, it is still a very lucrative market.

My tip would be to focus on more than just SharePoint. Office 365 and Windows Azure are things you need to fully cover as well in order to put yourself in a competitive spot on the market in the future - and to be honest, I think there's more to be done in development in general than in SharePoint infrastructure/admin.

Pay scales vary extremely much depending on your experience, skillset and role and is impossible to determine without knowing the variables to a specific situation.

All in all I'd say that it all varies depending on your own goals and roles. I hope you find your way :-)